# Spring Batch - How can I modify data from repository while browsing data page by page?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

Is there any ItemReader that permits to access the database repository and modifies the data in real-time? I have an issue while I am using the RepositoryItemReader in order to read the data from the repository and try to modify their status. 
While browsing the data page by page, it jumps at the next page without modifying the data. 
Will this use case be taken in consideration in the future releases?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is an effect of using paging instead use a cursor.

Comment: what I understand is that you want to modify objects returned from the query while you are still browsing the items. Am I right ?

Comment: is this the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320657/spring-batch-jpapagingitemreader-read-only-first-results) ?

Answer (score -1):

Spring Batch follows a standard pattern of

```
ItemReader()
ItemProcessor()
ItemWriter()
```

If you need to modify things you've read, you could setup the processor to change the status, then pass it to an ItemWriter to update the database.